# how to display new image using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?php echo $promotion_image;?>"  title="" alt="" height="50" width="50"><br/><br/><br/>
<input type="file" name="promotion_image" value="" id="promotion_image" class="form-control">
<a href ="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?php echo $promotion_image;?>">Preview</a>
```

Image is displaying. once i choose new file,it should change the existing image and it should be available for preview before updating.
Please help me out.

Comment: You have to use jquery plugin for uploading image.

Comment: See this, definitely help you http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/t6UP5/

Comment: Have you set your base url in the config.php if not then some images will not show or css links etc.

Comment: i wrote js file for this..i will check config also and get back to you people

Comment: when i click on edit,image icon is displaying in edit page but its not showing file name(showing :"no file choosen").

Comment: while retrieving data from database,filename is not displaying in field(input :type=file)